# How do I get the value of this textarea jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, closest

I am trying to get the value of the textarea (class="caption_textarea") when clicked on the link with class "save_caption".

The value of the textarea is changed with ajax and I am not including that here and therefore it is not always empty.

I have following HTML code:

```
  <div class="caption_text" style="display:none;">
      <div class="small_icons">
          <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="save_caption"><img src="<?php echo base_url('public/images/tick.png'); ?>"/></a>
          <a href=""><img src="<?php echo base_url('public/images/delete.png'); ?>"/></a>
      </div>
      <textarea id="<?php echo $image_name_without_path[0]; ?>" class="caption_textarea" cols="32" rows="2" name="caption_text"></textarea>
  </div>
```

I tried jquery's next, closest and find methods but I am unable to retrieve the value of the closest textfield's value to the a element clicked. Jquery code below:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.save_caption').live("click", function() {
           alert($(this).closest('textarea').find('.caption_textarea').val());
     });
 });
```

Comment: Just get rid of the `find` and your alert should work.

Comment: @Archer doesn't `closest()` search up the dom tree so it won't find the textarea at all. `$(this).closest('div.caption_text').find('textarea').val()`?

Comment: @MarkWalters Yep - my bad.  Thanks for pointing out what my sleep-filled eyes didn't notice :)

Comment: Thanks Mark. Your solution worked. Up-voted!
So why did the closest('textarea') didn't work and .closest('div.caption_text') works?

Comment: @user1293053 `$(this)` refers to the anchor tag you want to click. searching for the `.closest('textarea')` searches upwards (up the dom tree) until it finds a textarea. Your textarea sits below the anchor tag outside of the div `small_icons`. So finding the closest div with class `.caption_text` means we can then use `.find('textarea)` which searches within this div to find all that match our criteria. In your case we want the texarea. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.save_caption').live("click", function() {
          alert($(this).closest('.caption_text').find('.caption_textarea').val());
     });
 });
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/elawuw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

closest() looks for the closes **ancestor**. You might want to try **next()** or **nextAll()**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.save_caption').live("click", function() {
           alert($(this).next('textarea.caption_textarea').val());
     });
 })
```

or something similar should work fine.

Comment: could you try
    
    alert($(this).next('textarea').val());

Answer (score 0):

You can find the cpmmon parent `caption_text` using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) then find the textarea inside it using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('.save_caption').live("click", function() {
           alert($(this).closest('.caption_text').find('.caption_textarea').val());
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using closest? I'm possibly missing some detail of your code.
Either way, wouldn't the solution be:

```
alert($('.mytextarea').val());
```

Or:

```
alert($('.mytextarea').html());
```

If your problem is that the class isn't unique to that text area (I would use an id but that's up to you), try:

```
alert($(this).next().val());
```

You can use 'textarea.mytextarea' to keep it strictly to textareas or .next('textarea').

Corrections and editions are welcome.

ps: make sure "this" is giving you the correct element.

Comment: i don't know if `$(this).next().val()` works. But if it works you should write `$(this)`  and not `$('this')`. And `.next(textarea)` should be `.next('textarea')` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector a bit. First take parent of **.save_caption** then look for its siblings having **.caption_textarea** class. Your code is a bit modified below -

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $('.save_caption').live("click", function() {
               alert($(this).parent().siblings('.caption_textarea').val());
         });
     });
```

Hope it will work.